# Making TEdit Box Transparent in a TTabsheet

Tags: c++, c++builder, transparent

I am using C++ Builder XE.

I have had to replace some Tlabels in a tabsheet  with TEdit boxes to make the content copiable. Unfortunately, when I run my application in windows Xp or with windows classics theme, the background of the TEdit totally stands out and does not blend with the that of the TEdit.

I need help with that. preferrably without having to use JVCL or create a new component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There was no C++Builder 7. C++Builder was end-of-lifed after C++Builder 6 and then resurrected in C++Builder 2006.

Comment: It is very difficult to make `TEdit` transparent. There are third party edit components that support transparency, but you don't want to use them. See if this article helps: [“Transparent” TEdit on TTabSheet](http://www.ccrdude.net/archives/250). It is geared towards Delphi, but it applies to C++Builder as well.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the insight. I've tried that before. The result is satisfactory until you get to winXp, then the TEdit can't follow the TTabsheet background color anymore.